How to display text dialogue in a RPG using GML Code
I’m currently working on my first ever rpg game, and trying to figure out how to use GML code as this is my first time using the software.
Anyways, any ideas on how to code in-game dialogue? (e.g. using unicode text)

When I search "how to dialogue GameMaker", I get lots of hits for guides, examples, and tutorials. Can you show us what you've tried so far, based on your research from sources like these? Where specifically do you find you get stuck, or need help with something not covered in these existing resources?

Well, I once referred to a video on YouTube by Peyton Burnham, however was stump by on how does the code work

Would you like to edit your question to share a particular piece of code you found confusing, and describe what you find confusing about it? That will help users here identify what specific help you need to understand it, so they can help you effectively.
